# Proving the variance of residuals? Specifically, how to deal with the covariances of various terms?

Tags: regression, variance, residuals

I am trying to prove the variance of the residuals $r_i$ for a simple linear regression model. defining $r_i = y_i - \hat{y}$, here is what I have come up with so far:

$V(r_i)=V(y_i-\hat{y})=V(y_i-(b_0-b_1{x_i}))$

=$V(y_i-b_0+b_1{x_i})=V(y_i-\bar{y} + b_1\bar{x}-b_1{x_i})$

=$V(y_i-\bar{y}+b_1(\bar{x}-x_i))$

=$V(y_i)+V(\bar{y})+(\bar{x}-x_i)^2V(b_1) - Cov(y_i,\bar{y})-Cov(\bar{y},b_1)-Cov(y_i,b_1)$

Now, if all of the covariances are zero, then I think what I have is correct. However, I am unsure how to show that the covariances are zero, or even if they are zero.

Comment: Because the residuals sum to zero, perforce (unless the fit is perfect, rendering all residuals zero) at least one covariance must be strictly negative.  This follows immediately upon computing the variance of the sum in terms of the variances and covariances of the residuals.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance where I would recommend matrix algebra.

We have that the residuals are

$$
e=y-X\hat\beta=y-X(X'X)^{-1}X'y=(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')y\equiv My
$$
Hence, assuming a classical linear model with deterministic regressors (else, the statements are conditional on $X$)
$$
Cov(e)=Cov(My)=MCov(y)M'=M\sigma^2IM'=\sigma^2M,
$$
where the last line uses symmetry and idempotency of $M$. So the variances of the residuals are the diagonal elements of this matrix.

Since, in case of a simple linear regression, the diagonal elements of $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ are $$(1 \;\; x_i)'(X'X)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\x_i\end{pmatrix},$$ you can write the diagonal elements as
$$
\sigma^2\left(1-(1 \;\; x_i)'(X'X)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\x_i\end{pmatrix}\right).
$$
We also have
$$
(X'X)^{-1}=\frac{1}{n\sum_ix_i^2-(\sum_ix_i)^2}\begin{pmatrix}\sum_ix_i^2&-\sum_ix_i\\-\sum_ix_i&n\end{pmatrix},
$$
which may be a more explicit expression for the simple linear case.